# How to remove 'ng-select' dropdown arrow in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngselect

**How to remove 'ng-select' dropdown arrow in Angular?**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
      <ng-select
        id="selectServiceType"
        [items]="clientServiceTypes$ | async"
        placeholder="Select service type"
        bindLabel="name"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedServiceType"
        [clearable]="false"
        [readonly]="fieldNotEditable() || serviceTypesReadonly"
      ></ng-select>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add this style to your global `styles.css` file.

```css
.ng-arrow-wrapper {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your css:
try this:

```
.ng-select .ng-arrow-wrapper {
  display: none;
}
```

or this:

```
.ng-select .ng-arrow-wrapper .ng-arrow {
  border-color: none !important;
  border-style: none !important;
  border-width: 0 !important;
}
```